# document.getElementById giving Null by JS not by HTML

Tags: javascript, html

When I am defining my input tag in html and accessing in JS by id then I am getting my tag.

**HTML Code:**

```
<input class="easyui-combobox" name="language" style="width:30%;" id= "XX">
```

**JS Code:**

```
var cc = document.getElementById("XX");
```

Here things are fine.

But When I am creating from javascript and trying to access I am getting. I want dynamic So I need to create from JS.

**JS Code:**

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.className = 'easyui-combobox';
input.style = 'width:30%';
input.id = "XX";
```

Here I am getting null after applying this:

```
var cc = document.getElementById("XX");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to append your created element into the document using `document.body.appendChild(input);`

```js
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.className = 'easyui-combobox';
input.style = 'width:30%';
input.id = "XX";
document.body.appendChild(input);
console.log(document.getElementById("XX"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not appended your element

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.className = 'easyui-combobox';
input.style = 'width:30%';
input.id = "XX";
document.body.appendChild(input); 

var cc = document.getElementById("XX");
console.log(cc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append input element to document

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.className = 'easyui-combobox';
input.style = 'width:30%';
input.id = "XX";
document.body.appendChild(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created your element using -

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
```

Now you need to append it to HTML so that you can find it on DOM.

```js
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.className = 'easyui-combobox';
input.style = 'width:30%';
input.id = "XX";
document.body.appendChild(input); 

var fetchedElement = document.getElementById("XX");
console.log(fetchedElement);
```

> - `createElement()` creates an Element Node.
> - `appendChild()` adds your element node to DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The element has been created, but needs to be appended to the **DOM**.  Use the 
`appendChild()` or `insertBefore()` method.

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.className = 'easyui-combobox';
input.style = 'width:30%';
input.id = "XX";
document.body.appendChild(input);
```